# Se eu copiar direto a pasta do projeto do Visual Studio dá algum erro? Ou eu tenho que fazer algo a mais?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Eu queria copiar a Solution do Projeto para o meu professor, posso ir no local do arquivo e somente copiar o projeto e mandar pra ele que vai funcionar?

Comment: Sim, pode só copiar a pasta toda.

Comment: Coloca no github e dá o link p/ o seu professor :) hehe
http://gabsferreira.com/criando-e-enviando-arquivos-para-seu-repositorio-no-github/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copie tudo inclusive o arquivo .SLN

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou você pode fazer algo mais bacana e colocar no Git.

http://gabsferreira.com/criando-e-enviando-arquivos-para-seu-repositorio-no-github/

Answer (score 5):

De forma geral é para funcionar. Se o VS dele for da mesma versão. Se forma mais atual é provável que funcione, mesmo que precisa de uma conversão automática, em versões mais antigas que a sua tem uma chance maior de não funcionar.

Claro que o projeto precisa estar em ordem, precisa copiar direitinho (tudo), tem que colocar no lugar certo.

Se o projeto tiver dependências além do que tem por padrão no VS terá que instalar essas dependências, mas em exercícios e coisas do tipo é improvável que tenha dependências extras. Pelo menos não deveria.

Estamos falando do projeto, se a aplicação vai rodar já é outro problema. Mas aí já é problema de *deploy*.